# Is there a way to make JavaScript fail silently when trying to call a method on an undefined object?

Tags: javascript, oop, error-handling, undefined

Rather than having to check whether an object is defined or not, I'd like to be able to simply call a method on it and have it fail silently if the object is in fact undefined. So, rather than having to write the following:

```
if(obj.delegate && obj.delegate.closeMenu){
    obj.delegate.closeMenu();
}
```

I could just write the line inside the `if` statement: `obj.delegate.closeMenu()`. If `obj` has no delegate property, simply nothing would happen. Same thing if `delegate` does exist, but it has no `closeMenu()` method.

Is this possible? If so, please offer an implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s currently no reliable way to do this, without writing more code. You could use `try`-`catch`, for example:

```
try {
  obj.delegate.closeMenu();
} catch(e) {
  // fail silently
}
```

Note that the non-standard [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod) does what you want, although it’s not supported everywhere.

---

**Update:** In ES6, you could use a proxy to do something similar. For example:

```
function getProperty(target, name, receiver) {
  if (name in target) {
    return target[name];
  }
  // property does not exist
  var result = doSomethingElse();
  return result;
}

var object = return Proxy(something, {
  'get': getProperty
});
```

Comment: `__noSuchMethod__` can only intercept **calls to functions**. It does not work for properties. When `__noSuchMethod__` is properly implemented on `a`, `a.b.c()` will still throw an error, but `a.b().c()` won't.

Comment: @RobW Yeah, it really does what it says on the tin :)

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten your code a little like this...

```
if((obj.delegate||{}).closeMenu){
    obj.delegate.closeMenu();
}
```

---

Or even like this...

```
var noop = function(){}; // keep a noop function handy
```

```
 // then use it like this...
((obj.delegate||{}).closeMenu||noop)()
```

...although you'll be changing the calling context of `closeMenu` to the global (or `undefined` in strict), which is probably not wanted. Still thought you might find it interesting.

Comment: +1 because I haven't seen those syntactical shortcuts before, nor had I heard of a noop before. What is its function in the way you use it? And can you point me to a resource that documents the possible boolean checking shortcuts like this?

Comment: @maxedison: `noop` is just short for *no operation*. In other words, it's a function that does nothing. Here it is substituted if `closeMenu` doesn't exist. This way you can eliminate the `if()` statement, and just do the call. If `closeMenu` exists, it'll be called, otherwise `noop` will be called *(and will do nothing)*.

Comment: ...The `||` returns the first *truthy* operand *(if any)*. So `(obj.delegate||{})` will return the empty object `{}` if `obj.delegate` is `undefined`. As such, `.closeMenu` is accessed on either `obj.delegate` or an empty object. If the latter, `(obj.delegate||{}).closeMenu` will be `undefined`, so the `if()` will fail. Or in the case of the second example, if `(obj.delegate||{}).closeMenu` is `undefined`, then the `||` will return the `noop`, so that's what you'll call.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var delegate = obj.delegate;

if ( !delegate ) {

    // handle the case that there is no delegate object

} else {

    // work with delegate here
    delegate.closeMenu();    

}
```

Comment: Right, that's essentially what I'm doing (see the code in my post). I'm looking for a way to avoid the necessity of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as you described. A good bet is a `try { } catch { }` as Mathias suggested. Alternately, you can set delegate to a stub object as below:

```
if(obj.delegate === undefined) obj.delegate = { closeMenu:function(){} }
obj.delegate.closeMenu();
```

Comment: Actually, just this: `if ( !obj.delegate ) { obj.delegate = {}; }` would be enough...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That would still throw a TypeError if you tried to call `obj.delegate()`, just like `({})()` would.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Also, `closeMenu` would be `undefined` and would throw an error if it was called.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the wonderful [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore) library and write something ridiculous like:

`_(_(obj).has('delegate')).has('closeWindow') && obj.delegate.closeWindow()`

Not a lot less typing, but more compact...